# DNS for domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I purchase a domain name, do I also automatically get an ip address associated with that domain name?
Reason for asking this is because online explanations says DNS resolves your domain name to and ip address or the ip address is provisioned later once I create a web site and host it on a server, and that server ip address becomes the ip address which is associated with said domain name?

In my AWS account under domain records, NS has few lines of entries in the formate `ns-23.awsdns-02.com`. I understand that this is a DNS, but why do I have 4 or 5 of them, isn't one enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't get an IP when you purchase a domain. You need to purchase hosting, which will give you an IP address. In AWS you will typically provision an EC2 instance or load balancer, give that an elastic (aka fixed) IP address, that IP is used by the AWS domain name service which is called "Route 53".

Domain name servers tend to be set up in redundant clusters, if one goes down one of the others is used. You enter your name server addresses into your domain registrar, this tells the internet who knows what your domain IP address is.

Comment: In the context of your answer relating to AWS, what is the difference between DNS service in the first paragraph and the Name Server in the second paragraph?

Comment: Clarified. Same thing, different phrases.